# How to display a different link in the bottom left corner on anchor hover than the href attribute of the said anchor?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, search, safari

I've recently noticed something about Google search results. When using the latest version of Firefox, if you hover over a link provided by Google search results a nice link is displayed on the bottom left corner, but if you inspect that link you see the link is actually something else. A link to the root ie. google.com with appended query variables that I presume redirect you to the actual page when you click on the link.

I'm wondering how is this possible, to display a completely different link in the bottom left corner. I've seen there are similar questions and all suggest tempering with js or using a button. But I'm interested if anyone knows exactly how Google achieves this?

Edit:
Let's look at an example of what I mean. 
If I search for: Wikipedia, these are the results. Nothing special right?
[image: Search results]

If I hover the link nothing special here, I'd expect wikipedia.org

[image: On link hover]

Ha, but I'd be wrong, this is what the actual link is! Wikipedia the title is highlighted above is the link.

[image: Html view of the link]

And what happens if I use ctrl + click or cmd + click ? The true link is reviled and the page opens in a new tab.

[image: True link]

Now how does one achieve this? I think it js manipulating the browser window and I haven't find a way to do this exact thing.

Note: this behaviour is true on Firefox and Safari, but not Chrome. On Chrome the href tag is the actual link but uses an attribute ping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure how Google handles this because their JS is uglified, but if I had to guess, I think it would be something like this:

By looking DOM structure of search results, `a` element has `href` with previewing link and another tag `ping` with actual link. On click in JS it sets `ping` location (preventing default behavior).

[image: DOM structure of google.com search result]

Below is code how this can be achieved.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let element = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
  element.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
    event.target.setAttribute('href', event.target.getAttribute('other'))
  })
})
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com/" other="http://bing.com/">Link</a>
```

---

Below is alternative approach but it wont work for middle click.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let element = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
  element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    let link = event.target.getAttribute('other')
    window.location.href = link
  })
})
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com/" other="http://bing.com/">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know what js events to use or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with `<a href="http://theLinkInTheBottomLeft">https://theDisplayedLink</a>`

So since the a tag provides 1. the href link, which is the link you will be redirected to and the content between its brackets, you can differentiate the visible from the actionable.

Comment: Ok, this is not what I meant, sorry, I'll add an edit.